# How can I return a nullable short with nullable Boolean parameter

Tags: c#

```
public static short? ToShortNullable(this bool? b)
{       
     return b.HasValue ? null : (b.Value==true : 1 ? 0);
}
```

I have tried the above but the syntax is not happy,  I want to return `null` if `b is null`, `1` if `b is true` and `0` if `b is false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public static short? ToShortNullable(this bool? b)
{
  return   b == null ? null : b == true ? 1 : (short?) 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Only answer which works, Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems: one is that you have the syntax back to front with the `:` and `?` in `b.Value==true : 1 ? 0` and the other is that you have the logic back to front. You're trying to return null when `b` *does* have a value and trying to extract a value from `b` when it doesn't have one.

Try this:

```
public static short? ToShortNullable(this bool? b)
{       
     return b.HasValue ? (b.Value==true ? 1 : 0) : null;
}
```

And since `b.Value == true` is the same as `b.Value` you can simplify to:

```
public static short? ToShortNullable(this bool? b)
{       
     return b.HasValue ? (b.Value ? 1 : 0) : null;
}
```

[Try it on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eaCuMN). This works on the Roslyn 3.8 and .NET 5 compilers.

On .NET 4.7.2 the compiler isn't as good at inferring the type of the conditional operator. It sees that one branch appears to have integer type and the other branch has a `null` literal and doesn't know how to resolve these. You can help it out by telling it the type of `null` with `(short?)null`.

Comment: Cannot convert from int to ?short, this is the biggest issue I am facing as its also nullable return type its confusing me!

Comment: Biggest issue is that the return type needs to be nullable

Comment: You haven't specified your compiler/language version. I'm guessing you're using an older version. I've updated the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
return !b.HasValue ? null : (short)(b.Value ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Thanks ! Is the contexte provided by accepted answer : "try this" sufficient ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it modern and fancy:

```cs
public static short? ToShortNullable(this bool? b) => b switch
{
    true => 1,
    false => 0,
    _ => null
};
```

[See it in action in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xYHORX)

Comment: While clever, it doesn't illustrate why the OP's attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @DStanley maybe, but it's **explicitly** answering the OP, both the title of the question and what's written inside